# Strange escaping behaviour with Vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, handlebars.js

I'm using this code with the intent to create different tags, i.e. `item.tag` below:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <{{item.tag}}>
        {{item.data}}
    </{{item.tag}}>
</div>
```

With `items` defined as follows:

```
items: generateItems(2, i => ({
    id: 'item' + i,
    tag: 'hr',
    data: ''
}))
```

But the HTML inside the `div` after the code runs has the `<` and `>` escaped, even though they aren't inside `{{ }}`, so it looks like this:

```
&lt;hr&gt; &lt;/hr&gt;
```

But if I define the type explicitly:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <hr>
        {{item.data}}
    </hr>
</div>
```

The `<` and `>` are not escaped, and the horizontal rules display no problem.

I intend to use other tags besides `hr` so would like to be able to use `item.tag` some way.

Can anyone explain what is going on, and is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `<component :is="tag">` For example:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  data() {
    return {
      tag: 'button',
      othertag: 'hr'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div v-html id="demo">
  <component :is="tag">hello</component>
  <component :is="othertag"></component>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Any reason why it's escaping `<` and `>` to begin with?